# Admin LTE dashboard with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, adminlte

I am using ADMIN LTE dashboard with my React Application. I have added certain  tags in my Sidebar component along with font-awesome  icons. However when I click on the link, the font awesome icons are refreshed(it re-runs the scripts in index.html).

Following is the code of index.html

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="Description" content="Admin Panel">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/AdminLTE.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/_all-skins.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionicons.min.css" />
    <!-- For material UI  Roboto Font-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic" />
    <title>Parcel</title>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/581d5d54d2.js" ></script>
  </head>
  <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <div id="root" class="wrapper"></div>
    <noscript>Make sure your Javascript is enabled</noscript>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sidebar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default class SideBar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <aside className="main-sidebar">
                <section className="sidebar">
                    <ul className="sidebar-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/customers">
                                <i className="fa fa-user-circle"></i> <span>dashboard</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/customers">
                                <i className="fa fa-asterisk"></i> <span>Settings</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </section>
                </aside>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is because of the <a > tag used for navigation.
Use <link> instead of <a>.
It worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on an `<a>` tag tells the browser to send a GET request to the given URL and display the response which cause page reload between the requests and after every page load your scripts get initialized again.

If you want to initialize your application only once, then you want to create a Single Page Application (SPA). In this case I highly recommend to use [`react-router`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) and their components like `<Link>` or `<NavLink>` to generate links for specific pages (or states).

You can find some examples in the official doc of `react-router`:

> https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy